# microsoft graph api sdk returns null user even when the user is there

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to fetch a user from a tenant by email. It works when getting some users, but doesn't work when getting a particular user who happens to have a '+' in the email address. I am not sure if that character is the problem or if it's something else. The query below always returns null for that user. My question, is how do I figure out why it's returning null when the user is obviously there for that particular user? I checked Audit Logs in AD B2C tenant, but they only show logins or deletions. Where can I check what happened with the graph API call? Second question, why would it do this? The user is obviously there!

```
   public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
    {
        var clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(Globals.ClientId)
            .WithTenantId(Globals.TenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(Globals.ClientSecret)                
            .Build();
    
        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientapp);
    
        return new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
    }

 public static async Task<User> GetADUserAsyncByEmail(string email)
        {
            var graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
            try
            {
                Logger.Log(LogLevel.Trace, $"Contacting AD tenant {Globals.Tenant} for user {email}.");
                var users = await graphClient.Users
                            .Request()
                            .Filter($"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{email}' and c/issuer eq '{Globals.Tenant}')")
                            .Select("displayName,id,userPrincipalName")
                            .GetAsync();
                Logger.Log(LogLevel.Trace, $"Finished contacting AD tenant {Globals.Tenant} for user {email}.");
                var foundUser = users.FirstOrDefault();
                return foundUser;
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex, $"Error Alert:Encountered an exception when trying to get AD User {email}.");
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex, $"Error Alert:Encountered an exception when trying to get AD User {email}.");
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Any updates?

Comment: I did, although I haven't tried it yet. I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Microsoft graph's handling of `issuerAssignedId` is not perfect.

It will encode the request url to URL-encoded format with the content of `{email}` being ignored.

Nevertheless, it can still return the correct result for most symbols that have not been encoded. For example, "*".

"+" seems a bit special, and Microsoft graph does not handle it well.

As a workaround, you can use [Uri.EscapeDataString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Uri_EscapeDataString_System_String_) to encode the email and put it into filter.

```
 var encodedEmail = Uri.EscapeDataString(email);
```

AND

```
.Filter($"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{encodedEmail}' and c/issuer eq '{Globals.Tenant}')")
```